# Java error A JNI error has occurred occuring running simple program in the command window

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm taking a Java class on Pluralsite.  The first exercise is, of course, an Hello World program.  I'm using Intellij IDEA for my IDE.  I write the program, from a template:

[See code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cacp3.png)

I run the code in the IDE.  No problem.  The next step is to run if from the command prompt.  Per the class I put the location of the Java.exe in the JRE into my path.  I reboot just to be sure.  I open a command prompt as adminstrator in the directory where the program lives and start with "Java -version" and get

java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)

I type "Java Main" and I get:

I type "Java Main" and I get:
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 57.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

```
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

Running:
jdk-14
jre 1.8.0_241

I have uninstalled all things Java.  Then reinstalled.  I have uninstalled the IDE and reinstalled.
Googled all over about this, no joy.

Another co worker is taking the course, same thing,

I will reach out to the person conducting this, but wanted to get this question out there in case he says "Works for me".  Oh, Windows 10.

Comment: It means you compiled your java code with a JDK version which is greater than 8. Looks like your IDE is using JDK 14

Comment: The class files were compiled for Java 13, you try to run it with Java 8.

Comment: Open Project Structure Dialog in Idea (File/Project Structure); press "New" at "Project SDK" configuration, choose your Java 8 JDK directory and ensure that this JDK 8 is set as a Project SDK. Rebuild your project and try again.

Comment: If you select item _About_ under the _Help_ menu, it should display the JDK version that comes bundled with Intellij.